# JBOSS AS 7 TCP clustering on Centos 7 EC2 machine

Tags: java, linux, tcp, amazon-ec2, jboss7.x

I am making jboss tcp cluster on EC2 centos machine. For the same purpose i go through many article on web, one of which i mention below.

[Creating TCP cluster in JBoss AS 7.1 in standalone](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2015)

Problem :
When i run jboss in cluster mode with `sudo sh standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -b [INTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1` it shows **Number of cluster members: 1**

But when run on local windows machine it works fine. Please let me know whats the issue.

Comment: how many cluster members are you expecting to see? you are running more than one JBoss instance? you need to provide more detail

Comment: I am expected 2 cluster. As running 2 jboss running on different machine with same similar configuration as mentioned in the article